# Stored images(Longblob) in my database and I can't display it into a jlabel

Tags: mysql, swing, jdbc, blob

I'm trying to display images from database into jlabel
IMAGES = column name, currentuser.getText() = i have a text on the top which determines the column USERNAME in my database

EDITED - I really dunno what to do anymore, it's been a week but still i cant display the image from the database

```
public class MyProfile extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
Container c;
ResultSet rs;
Connection con;
Statement st;
TempData temp = new TempData(); //Class for storing current user who logins (Set & get)
JLabel currentuser = new JLabel("" + temp.getUsername());
JLabel displayPhoto = new JLabel();
public MyProfile() {
    super("My Profile");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1175, 698);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true)
    c = this.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pancakefinder", "root", "");
        st = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }

    c.add(currentuser);
    currentuser.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    currentuser.setForeground(Color.orange);

    c.add(displayPhoto);
    displayPhoto.setBounds(160, 330, 250, 230);
    displayPhoto();
}

public void displayPhoto() {
    try {
       PreparedStatement pst = null;
       rs = null;
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select IMAGES from  images where USERNAME = '" + currentuser.getText() + "'");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        byte[] bytes = null;
        if (rs.next()) {
            bytes = rs.getBytes("images");
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bytes);
            displayPhoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon((img)));
            displayPanel.add(displayPhoto);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
public static void main(Stringp[] args){
MyProfile ex = new MyProfile();
```

}
}

Comment: "*I can't display the image*" is not a problem description that will get you any help. Do you get an error or an exception? If yes, which one? Is the image not displayed? Is the image corrupted? What *do* you get?

Comment: There's no error or any exception, but the image isn't there yet, corrupted? i guess not i tried uploading new image and still not. My presentation on wednesday and this is the last part that i need :(

Comment: I tried this
   if (rs.next());
            InputStream binaryStream = new BufferedInputStream(rs.getBinaryStream("IMAGES"));
            image = ImageIO.read(binaryStream);
            displayPhoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

and nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `displayPanel` is a `JPanel` and `displayPhoto` is the `JLabel`. If `displayPhoto` was added before `pack()`, `setIcon()` should be enough. If not, you'll need to `revalidate()` the panel after `add()`. Also check if the `rs.next()` result is `false`, and remember that it will only fetch one row; you'll need a loop to get any other rows.